# how to perform left click and drag to right slide button with selenium in python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-chromedriver, drag-and-drop

How can I perform a left click and drag to right slide (with approximately 1 second transition time) with selenium in python.

Before drag

[image]

```
<div style="display:inline-block;" tabindex="11" class="slide-submit" id="continueId">
    <button type="submit" class="ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle" style="left: 0px; top: 0px;">move me<span class="arrow-right"> →</span></button>
    <label>drag to continue</label>
</div>
```

After drag

[image]

```
<div style="display:inline-block;" tabindex="11" class="slide-submit" id="continueId">
    <button type="submit" class="ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle ui-draggable-dragging" style="left: 123px; top: 0px;">move me<span class="arrow-right"> →</span></button>
    <label>drag to continue</label>
</div>
```

python: 3.11.1,  ChromeDriver: 109.0.5414.74, Selenium: 4.8.0

Comment: What version of Selenium?

Comment: Selenium 4.8.0. Post updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried `action_chains`

**import**

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
```

**Element to drag**

```
drag_element = driver.find_element_by_class_name("ui-draggable")
```

**Perform the drag**

```
action = ActionChains(driver)
action.click_and_hold(drag_element)
action.move_by_offset(125, 0)
action.release().perform()
```

**Note:** Try the offset `X` and `Y` according to need.